# Get the specified row value of a given pandas dataFrame and how to get the column information it belongs to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
a=len(df2.columns) - 1

criteria = df2[df2.iloc[:,a]<= -80 ]
```

This code returns values ​​greater than 80 in the dataframe.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akr57.png)

but I don't want all the columns. I want the value satisfying the condition and the column to which it belongs. the output I want is as follows, containing only index and column information. how can I do that ?

| datetime | 400-approve-packages |
| --- | --- |
| 08:00 | -100 |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but I would recommend you this way :

`criteria = df2[df2.a <= -80 ].a.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the columns one by one.

```
for c in df.columns:
    print(df[df[c]<=80][c])
```